# IQR for Normal Probability Distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

I was attempting to find the IQR for a normal distribution with mean being 4.5, while the standard deviation.

My attempt yielded the result **2.144**, while the actual answer provided was **2.1584**.

Following is my workings, appreicate if anyone will be able to guide me where I am going wrong please:

> X ~ N(4.5, 1.6^2)
>
> P(A < X < B) = 0.5
>
> thus using table 4 allows us to deduce that Za = -0.67, while Zb = 0.67.
>
> using the formulae x = z . Population sd + population mean,
>
> A = (-0.67)(1.6) + 4.5 = 3.428
>
> B = (0.67)(1.6) + 4.5 = 5.572

Thus, for IQR, I took 5.572 - 3.428 = 2.144.

Comment: Your first sentence is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your answer differs from the one you were given is that the Z values you used were only to two [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Arithmetic), and the figures given in the question also appear to only be accurate to two figures. Immediately, the precision in your answer would be about two significant figures. (That is, you can pretty much only say it's "2.1-something", and your answer is accurate to that extent.)

If your figures and tables are only to that many places, then you can't expect to produce answers to 4 or 5 figure accuracy.

To 5 figures, the upper quartile of a standard normal is 0.67449. If we pretend the mean and standard deviation are accurate to a similar number of figures (4.5000, 1.6000 respectively), you should try using that Z value and see how you get 2.1584 (taken to 5 figures).

Comment: Thank you so much Glen! You made me learn a lesson here: I should always do the rounding at the final stages to get better and more accurate results! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, for hand computation, it's important to always leave rounding to the end.